# Convert 64 bit Integer hex string to 64 bit decimal string on 32 bit system

Tags: php

What is a simple way to convert a 64 bit integer encoded as a hex string to a decimal string on a 32 bit system. It needs to be the full value, it can not be in scientific notation or truncated :/

"0c80000000000063" == "900719925474099299"

"0c80000000000063" != 9.007199254741E+17

PHP's base_convert() and hexdec() don't do the job right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) PHP extension (bundled).

First split your input string to get high and low bytes, next convert it to decimal and then do calculation via BC functions like this:

```
$input = "0C80000000000063";

$str_high = substr($input, 0, 8);
$str_low = substr($input, 8, 8);

$dec_high = hexdec($str_high);
$dec_low  = hexdec($str_low);

//workaround for argument 0x100000000
$temp = bcmul ($dec_high, 0xffffffff);
$temp2 = bcadd ($temp, $dec_high);

$result = bcadd ($temp2, $dec_low);

echo $result;

/*
900719925474099299
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the first comment to hexdec's help page on php.net?

> When given large numbers, the hexdec function automatically converts
>   the value to scientific notation.  So, "aa1233123124121241" as a
>   hexadecimal value will be converted to "3.13725790445E+21".  If you're
>   converting a hexadecimal value that represents a hash value (md5 or
>   sha), then you need every single bit of that representation to make it
>   useful.  By using the number_format function, you can do that
>   perfectly.  For example :

```
<?php

            // Author: holdoffhunger@gmail.com

        // Example Hexadecimal
        // ---------------------------------------------

    $hexadecimal_string = "1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef";

        // Converted to Decimal
        // ---------------------------------------------

    $decimal_result = hexdec($hexadecimal_string);

        // Print Pre-Formatted Results
        // ---------------------------------------------

    print($decimal_result);

            // Output Here: "2.41978572002E+37"
            // .....................................

        // Format Results to View Whole All Digits in Integer
        // ---------------------------------------------

            // ( Note: All fractional value of the
            //         Hexadecimal variable are ignored
            //         in the conversion. )

    $current_hashing_algorithm_decimal_result = number_format($decimal_result, 0, '', '');

        // Print Formatted Results
        // ---------------------------------------------

    print($current_hashing_algorithm_decimal_result);

            // Output Here: "24197857200151253041252346215207534592"
            // .....................................

?>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It just expands it. 0c80000000000062 != 900719925474099328

Comment: This is false, number_format will use a rounded number. 0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef == 24197857200151252728969465429440056815 (base 10)